# Run Bat file in Administrator Mode

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd

```
runas.exe /profile /user:administrator "C:\temp\SQLSP3.bat"
```

will run the SQLSP3.bat file in Administrative Prompt and it is asking Adminstrator password in Windows Server 2008.

SQLSP3.bat file has following code

```
C:\Temp\SQLSP3.exe /qs /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms /Action=Patch /AllInstances
```

Is there any option which i can code the Administrator Password in any of the Script file ?

I don't want UAC to ask me the password. Everything needs to happen silently.
Please help me.

Comment: It is never a good idea to mention a password (literally) in a batch file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to code it inside the batch file ? If so then use the pipe command, write this before the code which is asking you for password

```
echo writepasshere| codehere
```

After that use this batch will make it silent . If you belong to the local administrators on the certain computer you could create a scheduled task that opens a command prompt with highest privileges.

To create such a scheduled task you could use a batch file (that you have to right-click and Run As Administrator once of course).

```
@echo off &setlocal
cd /d "%~dp0"

for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%i in ('chcp') do set /a oemcp=%%~ni
>nul chcp 1252

set "taskname=Elevated CMD Prompt"
set "exec=C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"
set "args=/k cd /d "%userprofile%""
set "xmlfile=task.xml"

set "line_01=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>"
set "line_02=<Task version="1.2"                   `                x   x 
set "line_03=  <Triggers />"
set "line_04=  <Principals>"
set "line_05=    <Principal id="Author">"
set "line_06=      <UserId>%userdomain%\%username%</UserId>"
set "line_07=      <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>"
set "line_08=      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>"
set "line_09=    </Principal>"
set "line_10=  </Principals>"
set "line_11=  <Settings>"
set "line_12=    <Enabled>true</Enabled>"
set "line_13=    <Hidden>true</Hidden>"
set "line_14=    <Priority>5</Priority>"
set "line_15=  </Settings>"
set "line_16=  <Actions Context="Author">"
set "line_17=    <Exec>"
set "line_18=      <Command>%exec%</Command>"
set "line_19=      <Arguments>%args%</Arguments>"
set "line_20=    </Exec>"
set "line_21=  </Actions>"
set "line_22=</Task>"

<nul >"%xmlfile%" set /p "=ÿþ"
>>"%xmlfile%" cmd /u /q /c "for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%i in ('set line_')                 

>nul chcp %oemcp%

schtasks /create /xml "%xmlfile%" /tn "%taskname%" /f
del "%xmlfile%"

pause
```

If the batchfile run successfully create a shortcut with target

```
C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /run /tn "Elevated CMD Prompt" /i
```

Now edit this line to where your .bat is, for example

```
set "args=/c "%temp%\elevated.bat""
```

and write your code in that file

After that run the shotcurt and bingo !
Plz vote this up if it helped you.

Regards,

Charchit

The script was taken from http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=544

Answer (score 0):

Create a scheduled task to run as the administrator account and save the credentials with the task.